# Drag and drop multiple files in the VSE?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Is there a way to drag and drop multiple video files in the VSE at once?

Comment: At once I assume?

Comment: Yes trying to drag and drop several files at once.

Comment: this question shows little research effort.

Answer (score 5):

Not by dragging directly form the OS (at least in Windows).

But you can import several video files simultaneously by selecting them on the file browser window.

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to add a video track.

On the file browser window use <kbd>Shift</kbd> to select more than one file manually

<kbd>A</kbd> to select all.

<kbd>B</kbd> to drag-select.

All the selected files will be imported sequencially on a single time line:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Bonus tip:** If you want these clips to be stacked on each other, select all then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to snap them to green playhead. They will stack vertically.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can but you have to do it using the modal file selector which opens by using "Add > Movie Clip" from the sequencer.

You cannot drag-and-drop from the file browser pane which shows by default in Blender 2.8's Video Editing view preset.